# Переопределение статических функций в потомках

Tags: ооп, c++

Можно ли статические функции-члены класса переопределять в классах потомках? или это какой-то бред и на то они статические ,что нельзя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переопределить можно:

```
struct Base
{
  static void foo(){}
};

struct Derr : Base
{
  static void foo(){}
}
```

Всё равно вызывать их, что внутри других (не)статических методов, что "снаружи" класса нужно будет как `Base::foo` и `Derr::foo`. Можно конечно внутри методов класса и просто `foo` писать, но тогда для каждого класса будет вызывана своя функция. Если функция не переопределена в производном, то будет вызвана функция базового класса.